# Automatically redirect to login.aspx on submit

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication

My application is showing strange behaviour. Whenever I press submit button on a page to save it redirects to /login.aspx automatically. The user is signed in and the code doesn't redirect to login.aspx. I've searched all solution files but I never found the text "login.aspx" and database also doesn't contain "login.aspx". I wonder how the system redirects to this page. Also this page doesn't exist in my application.
Please notice that this issue is only on live site.
Here's the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /login.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4211; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was due to write permission on a folder.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using forms authentication with a redirect URL in the web.config. Check in the web.config under the authentication node.

Comment: No the web.config doesn't contain login.aspx. Web.config has <authentication mode="Forms" /> instead.

Comment: That's your problem, you need the <forms name="blahblah"
loginUrl="~/Login.aspx">

Comment: I have not specified login.aspx anywhere. This is the problem I'm asking that why is it going to login.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Nuget](http://nuget.org/)
2. Add the [Elmah](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/elmah) package to your project.
   (Grab a beer)
3. Check your sessions are persisting correctly.
4. Check that `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is True.
5. Check your Web.Config and IIS settings for Forms Authentication.
6. Re register ASP.Net with your IIS install (google `aspnet_regiis`).
7. Specify a default login page like this:

   ```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="~/Signin.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Dashboard.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
   </authentication>
   ```

This Forms Authentication tutorial might be valuable:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article141.aspx

Comment: This issue is only on live site. it runs fine on local host.

Comment: All the more reason to check IIS settings, Web.Config settings and possibly re register ASP.Net with the production IIS (if possible). Remember your local debug server is Cassini and your production server could be IIS7.0.

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings on your live server, it may be forcing timeouts as a global setting.

Also, as Jeremy Child pointed out, set the authentication forms loginUrl to the page where you do your authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Check your framework versions web.config at  C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Web.config (or whatever version .net you are using) to make sure someone didn't add it there as a default.
remember 3.5 and 3.0 both use the 2.0 web.config